# Reference request for Lie algebras

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry, galilean-relativity

My future adviser just published a beautiful paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08304, and I am looking for some references/textbooks to look into the following concepts:

- Lie algebra (central) extensions
- Poincaré algebra
- Galilean algebra
- Maurer–Cartan forms

Comment: For some brief notes on the maurer cartan form read the relevant parts of lecture 1 "Connections on principal fibre bundles" from this web page https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I asked there as well, but being as I'm a physicist, just one who wants to foster a greater degree of communication between mathematics and physics, I thought it appropriate to post in the physics stack as well.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3194902/11127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the book ["Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, Cohomology and some Applications in Physics" by de Azcárraga and Izquierdo](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lie-groups-lie-algebras-cohomology-and-some-applications-in-physics/B570D04EC2EAA2A2C21BA23F245D2457) covers most of the topics (as you can easily see by looking at the Index).

It is mathematically rigorous but geared towards physical applications and does not need a lot of prerequisites. That it is written by one of the authors of the paper you mention might be an additional benefit.

Comment: This is a brilliant field! Thank you so much!